# Glass Mapper handling fields with spaces change in 4.3

Tags: glass-mapper

I'm using the most recent Glass Mapper, the 4.3.x version (with Sitecore 8.2 Update 1), in a project for the first time. Lately my standard deal after installing Glass is to add the following line to the GlassMapperScCustom.cs file:

```
dependencyResolver.DataMapperResolverFactory.Add(() => new DataMapperFieldsWithSpace());
```

In 4.2.x this worked fine, but in 4.3.x I'm getting a "The type or namespace name 'DataMapperFieldsWithSpace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" error.

Was this baked into the standard resolvers in 4.3.x and no longer has to be declared, or did the pipeline changes described in the release notes of the blog make this call changed, and it needs to be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to use AbstractDataMapperFieldsWithSpace. I verified  source code and looks like AbstractDataMapperFieldsWith space is the name of new class

Please see below picture:

[image]

Comment: That compiles, so I think it's good to go. Thanks!